# How to checkout to a different branch in submodules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-submodules

We are have 2 rails projects for which /models are common for both of the projects and so we maintained a separate repo by using submodules concept.

Now in project1 I created a branch `rails3_upgrade` from master for my submodules i.e., in app/models.

how can I checkout to that branch in project2 models from master?

I tried `get fetch --all` and `git remote -v` and some other options but couldn't see the branch I created.

Googled but couldn't find. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: in this case, you can do `pull request`  for project2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777854/git-submodules-specify-a-branch-tag)

Answer (score 0):

A branch created in a parent repo project1 won't be visible by other repos (submodules or project2)

You can create that branch in a submodule of Project1, and see it in the same submodule in project2

```
cd /path/to/project1/submodule1
git checkout -b newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch

cd /path/to/project2/submodule1
git fetch
git checkout newBranch --track origin/newBranch
```

As usual, is you make any modification in a submodule, don't forget to add and commit in the parent repo as well.

Creating a branch in a submodule does not mean the submodule will always checkout the latest of that branch though.
For that, see "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)" I wrote before.
And for the submodule to update itself to the latest of that branch, you would need a

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Comment: HI, I created a branch in my submodule only in Project1. I mean my app/models are submodules for both Project1 and Project2. So in Project1 I moved to app/models and from master I created a branch `new_branch`.
After that I went to Project2 app/models and I tried to checkout to the branch which I created in Project1 app/models(`new_branch`).

Comment: @Thisisme OK, but did you push the branch you created in project1/app/models? Because app/model is its own git repo, and the same git repo in project2 will need to fetch that branch before being able to checkout it.

Comment: Yes I pushed and I can see the branch in the github repo as well. I have lot of commits in that branch as well.

Comment: @Thisisme So what is your question? What is the problem? Are you able or not to see that same branch and commits in your same submodule in project2?

Comment: Yes, am not able to see the branch in project2

Comment: @This project2 would not see a branch created in another repo. Only Project2/app/model would see that branch